# Nginx can't find phpMyAdmin

Tags: nginx

Hello I have installed the newest stable Version of Nginex (1.4.4) and want to install also phpMyAdmin, unfortunately the following error appears when I try to open phpMyAdmin in my browser through http:// 192 . . . /phpmyadmin:

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.4.4
```

What exactly is the reason that Nginx can't find the phpMyAdmin file?

This is the content of my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Many Greetings

Comment: where is phpmyadmin installed ?

Answer (score 4):

It's really not a good idea to make a symbolic in your document root, that's just asking for trouble having a phmyadmin shortcut in www.

The right way to do it is to create a file called php and add to /etc/nginx/sites-available. You can copy the file below but change the port number to something else.

```
    server {
        listen 30425;

        # Don't want to log accesses.
        #access_log  /dev/null main;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/php.acces_log main;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/php.error_log info;

        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        error_page 401 403 404 /404.php;

        location ~ .*.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;

        }
}
```

Now you need to make symbolic link to sites enabled directory

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/php//etc/nginx/sites-enabled

now you need to add this code to Logging Settings part of nginx.conf

```
log_format main ‘$remote_addr – $remote_user [$time_local] ‘
                ‘”$request” $status $body_bytes_sent “$http_referer” ‘
                ‘”$http_user_agent” “$http_x_forwarded_for”‘ ;
```

Now you can access your phpmyadmin with http://example.com:30425

Comment: Don't forget to add the port to your firewall if you have one configured

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the instructions on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server and linked nginx and phpMyAdmin through the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/html
(the folder "www" was replaced in the newer versions of Nginx through "html")
sudo service nginx restart
```

If I now try to start phpMyAdmin through
"http:// 192 . . . /phpmyadmin"
the following error appears in my browser:

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.4.4
```

If I try to start phpMyAdmin through
"http:// 192 . . . /phpmyadmin/index.php"
the index.php file only gets downloaded.

Many Greetings

Comment: maybe the php-fpm service is not started

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided here did not help me for reasons unknown. I suspect that other parts of my conf file ruled out going into the phpmyadmin directory.

Not wanting to spend too long fixing it to work I simply copied my working conf file from www.example.com to phpmyadmin.example.com and set the directory to /usr/share/phpmyadmin. I then did nginx -s reload and I was good to go without ever having to get to the bottom of the 403/502 errors that I encountered doing it properly. I also believe that http://phpmyadmin.example.com is more secure from random hackers trying their scripts than the http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin domain, however it does entail having the wildcard setup correctly for the DNS for your domain, i.e. so that the address resolves to your server.

Hope this helps anyone frustrated in the simple task of getting phpmyadmin working with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

As user1941083 explain.
You just need to create a symbolic link between phpMyAdmin and your site’s directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/www
```

And after that, modify nginx setting in /etc/nginx/sites-available.
Change :

```
index index.html index.html;
```

to :

```
index index.html index.html index.php;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try by using `http://domain-name-or-ip-address/phpmyadmin/index.php`

Sometime Nginx do not use index.php automatically, we have to tell it, either by changing location in `nginx.conf` file or by adding `index.php` manually into url, just like above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late though but I had the same problem after following some tutorials and suggestions online but to no avail. I also tried @STH answer on this page but still error still exist.

I had to restart the following services:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

**THIS DID THE TRICK:** Configure the Daemons to Start at Boot, to ensure that all of the LEMP programs start automatically after any server restarts:

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx mysqld php-fpm
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to create the symbolic link between the phpmyadmin location and nginx www:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

after this you can get the 403 Forbidden but should add the index.php inside the server tag where index.html and others are:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and then restart nginx